# what is the corresponding matplotlib code of this matlab code

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I'm trying to go away from matlab and use python + matplotlib instead. However, I haven't really figured out what the matplotlib equivalent of matlab 'handles' is. So here's some matlab code where I return the handles so that I can change certain properties. What is the exact equivalent of this code using matplotlib? I very often use the 'Tag' property of handles in matlab and use 'findobj' with it. Can this be done with matplotlib as well?

```
% create figure and return figure handle
h = figure();
% add a plot and tag it so we can find the handle later
plot(1:10, 1:10, 'Tag', 'dummy')
% add a legend
my_legend = legend('a line')
% change figure name
set(h, 'name', 'myfigure')
% find current axes
my_axis = gca();
% change xlimits
set(my_axis, 'XLim', [0 5])
% find the plot object generated above and modify YData
set(findobj('Tag', 'dummy'), 'YData', repmat(10, 1, 10))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [findobj](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.findobj) method is matplotlib too:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

h = plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(1,11), range(1,11), gid='dummy')
my_legend = plt.legend(['a line'])
plt.title('myfigure')  # not sure if this is the same as set(h, 'name', 'myfigure')
my_axis = plt.gca()
my_axis.set_xlim(0,5)
for p in set(h.findobj(lambda x: x.get_gid()=='dummy')):
    p.set_ydata(np.ones(10)*10.0)
plt.show()
```

Note that the `gid` parameter in `plt.plot` is usually used by matplotlib (only) when the backend is set to 'svg'. It use the `gid` as the `id` attribute to some grouping elements (like `line2d`, `patch`, `text`).

Comment: great! so is the 'gid' property in matplotlib similar to the 'Tag' property in matlab, i.e, does it exist for any kind of object (figure, plot, legend).

Comment: No, `plt.figure` and `plt.legend` do not accept the `gid` parameter. If you need to keep track of groups of objects in general, it might be easier to use a dict which maps from tag names like `'dummy'` to lists of objects. Then you don't need rely on `matplotlib`'s `findobj` either.

Comment: but in that case I need to always store the list of objects somewhere. That's the beauty of findobj - I can find objects that don't be long together and I don't need to explicitly save those object (and pass them on).

Comment: findobj in matplotlib also works recursively and you can select objects based on any set of properties, existence of attributes, container/containment relations and class. So it has the same powers as that in matlab. The artist tutorial shows a huge range of properties you can set and much more: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html. Read the docs and cookbooks- there is a huge amount of power and flexibility there.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used matlab but I think this is what you want

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,3,4,5,6]
y = [1,9,16,25,36]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  # add a plot
ax.set_title('y = x^2')
line1, = ax.plot(x, y, 'o-')       #x1,y1 are lists(equal size)
line1.set_ydata(y2)                #Use this to modify Ydata
plt.show()
```

Of course, this is just a basic plot, there is more to it.Go though [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) to find the graph you want and view its source code.

Comment: you don't modify the YData once you've plotted them. If a 'findobj' equivalent doesn't exist in matplotlib, then I'd like to see how to do this differently. Thanks!

Comment: just an addition: if you want to update ydata dynamically (as in interactive mode or for animation), you have to refresh the figure after set_ydata() by calling the draw() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
# create figure and return figure handle
h = figure()

# add a plot but tagging like matlab is not available here. But you can
# set one of the attributes to find it later. url seems harmless to modify.
# plot() returns a list of Line2D instances which you can store in a variable  
p = plot(arange(1,11), arange(1,11), url='my_tag')

# add a legend
my_legend = legend(p,('a line',)) 
# you could also do 
# p = plot(arange(1,11), arange(1,11), label='a line', url='my_tag')
# legend()
# or
# p[0].set_label('a line')
# legend()

# change figure name: not sure what this is for.
# set(h, 'name', 'myfigure') 

# find current axes
my_axis = gca()
# change xlimits
my_axis.set_xlim(0, 5)
# You could compress the above two lines of code into:
# xlim(start, end)

# find the plot object generated above and modify YData
# findobj in matplotlib needs you to write a boolean function to 
# match selection criteria. 
# Here we use a lambda function to return only Line2D objects 
# with the url property set to 'my_tag'
q = h.findobj(lambda x: isinstance(x, Line2D) and x.get_url() == 'my_tag')

# findobj returns duplicate objects in the list. We can take the first entry.
q[0].set_ydata(ones(10)*10.0) 

# now refresh the figure
draw()
```

Comment: if you install ipython, which has special matplotlib support, you can use it interactively like matlab(with tab-key-autocompletion). run: ipython -pylab

Comment: if matlab like tagging is not available, can I tag (and find) objects differently?

Comment: yeah, I just updated the answer. and here you can have as much complexity in your search criteria(way beyond tagging) as you want.